# how to build hive ODBC drivers?

Tags: hive, unixodbc

I built the Hive ODBC Drivers on REDHAT by https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveodbc.html,
every step is successful, but in the end I don't find the Drivers file in /Drivers/hive/.libs/, why ?